# How do you check for equality between a jquery .html() variable and ruby on rails generated html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Currently I am trying to compare two variables, `newhtml` and `oldhtml`. 
I get the old html using:

```
var oldhtml = $('#pop').html();
```

I get the new html using:

```
var newhtml = ("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'shared/_content') %>");
```

I'm then trying to compare them using:

```
if(newhtml == oldhtml)
{
  //is never called
  $('#pop').hide();
}
else
{
  //is always called
  $('#pop').html(newhtml);
}
```

but it's not working. In this scenario the `oldhtml` variable is actually just the previous `newhtml` variable. So, if you click on the same content on the main page `newhtml` should actually just be a ruby on rails generated version of `oldhtml` (the html present in `<div id="pop">`). I've tried appending them to see where there difference lies, but it looks exactly the same to me. I was hoping someone could nudge me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: How does the `var newhtml = ...` line work? Does it get live content (ajax-wise) or is it a one-off string determined when the page is served?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I don't believe it is live content. It is accessing content that can be added live using ajax, but at the moment it is getting the html, everything would already be in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was all very helpful and I actually sort of combined the answers to get something that worked. What ended up working is this:

Get the oldhtml like before:

```
var oldhtml = $('#pop').html();
```

Then insert the new html into the div:

```
$('#pop').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'shared/_content') %>");
```

Following that, get the newhtml from the div, the same way I retrieved the oldhtml:

```
var newhtml = $('#pop').html();
```

The if statement then works, but you want to make sure to change the div to something arbitrary that can't be retrieved from your database:

```
if(newhtml == oldhtml)
{
$('#pop').html("<h>toggled_off</h>");
$('#pop').hide();
}
else
{
$('#pop').html(newhtml);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to put the newhtml in a hidden DOM element and then get that content back from jquery `.html()`

```
$('#HiddenDOM').html(newhtml);

if ($('#HiddenDOM').html() === $('#pop').html()) { ... }
```

Not tested but might cancel out html rendering issues.

Also, use triple equality comparison for javascript: `===` instead of `==` . See Cockford on Javascript The Good Parts on youtube for an explanation.

Overall, I'd rethink your design because the comparison might not be truly possible and would open your architecture to all sort of browser mysteries. Sometimes, you first have to find out what doesn't work to get to the working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall any guarantees regarding the formatting of the html returned by `html()`, particularly whitepace.

But, at least when I pull a chunk of HTML out of a page in firefox, what comes out seems to be formatted the same as how it was sent by the server.

So, perhaps there are only trivial differences between the strings, e.g. in leading and trailing whitespace.  Try using a function line this to compare the two HTML snippets:

```
function compare_html(a,b) {
    a = a.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"");
    b = b.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"");
    return a == b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation warns that with `.html()` "some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document". This will also apply to dynamically inserted HTML.

Your best bet is to compare two javascript strings, neither of which is read back from the DOM.

eg:

```
var newhtml = ("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'shared/_content') %>"),
    oldhtml = newhtml;

...

if(newhtml == oldhtml)
{
  $('#pop').hide();
}
else
{
  oldhtml = newhtml;
  $('#pop').html(newhtml);
}
```

It's undoubtedly more complicated than this but I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

strip the tags of both htmls and then compare with ==

`var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");